# Could synthetic fibers be environmentally-friendly, can you deal with the issue of microfibers?

Tags: plastic, pollution, clothing

Synthetic fibers [make up](https://quantis-intl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/measuringfashion_globalimpactstudy_full-report_quantis_cwf_2018a.pdf) the largest share of total apparel production and are expected to become even more common. They also, it [seems](https://hs0010910.jnu.edu.cn/_upload/article/files/40/1a/ec492aca44bc8826b64c4749219c/8c5d440e-b209-4646-8e10-b218eaf5c7af.pdf), contribute to microplastic pollution more than anything else. Could synthetic fibers be ever environmentally-friendly, can you deal with the issue of microfibers (for example, by replacing oil-based polyester with bio-based one, I'm not sure there's a difference)? Or do you have to get rid of this phenomenon altogether?